# didReceiveRemoteNotification - call function in the current view controller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, push-notification

How can i fire a function of a current view controller(currently user viewing) when i receiving a push notification.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method is to, in your app delegate's method to handle the remove notification, send out a notification using NSNotificationCenter

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:@"remoteNotification" withObject:whateverYouWantHere];
```

Then use the NSNotificationCenter to add any interested UIViewController's as an observer for the "remoteNotification" name.